# How to update "TrackingNumber" field in QuickBook invoice?

Tags: quickbooks, invoice, qbxml

I want update "TrackingNumber" field value in Invoice related request query. So which request query i used for updating "TrackingNumber"?

I checked in "InvoiceModRq" request but there is not declare any field with the name of "TrackingNumber".

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

QuickBooks does not support updating this field programatically yet.

Comment: Is it possible with QBXML request?

Comment: No, as indicated above, it's not supported.